# Floating IPs not released when deleting instance

Tags: ibm-cloud, openstack-horizon

In Bluemix's VM Service, I've been creating instance using floating IPs from the Public-Network. Most of the time when I delete an instance, the IP is released. However, after a few weeks of testing, I see that 3 out of my 11 floating IPs are still allocated. Is there a way to unallocate them? To reiterate: I do *not* currently have any instances.

This looks like the old bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/nova/+bug/997763, which was supposedly fixed in Folsom.

Comment: Do you use Horizon dash board do delete instances or Bluemix UI ? If you delete the VM group through Bluemix UI, IPs would be released . If you do it through openstack/horizon, then you would have to manually release them.

Comment: I use horizon. So, how would you manually release them?

Comment: Click on Access & Security tab --> Floating IPs in Horizon dashboard,

Comment: @vmovva Well that's embarrassing. I was only looking for it in the Network section. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your issue, click on Access & Security tab --> Floating IPs in Horizon dashboard
Select all. Release all.